# checking a private variable using a derived class object

Tags: c++, inheritance

below is the small program.
i want to check the value of the private variable x of class A using the object of class B.
is it possible ever?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>

class A {
    int x;
public:
    A() {
        x=10;
    }
};

class B : public A { 
public:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    B obj;
    obj.x=20;
    std::cout<< obj.x;
    getch();
}
```

This will output `20`, but how can i check the value of `x` as 10 which is in `class A`?
i wanted to know whether we can check the value without making x as protected!

Comment: Why not use, say, a protected accessor?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to make the variable protected, or, you can create a protected member method in class A which returns the variable x.

By using the 2nd approach (protected member method or property (is that possible in C++?), class B can read the variable, but cannot change it.

Comment: Protected in c++ gives full access to derived classes. If you want to give derived classes read-only access then use a protected access method.

Answer (score 1):

Derived classes cannot see ancestor privates.   You can use "protected" for descendents to see the data, but not unrelated classes.

Comment: i wanted to know whether we can check the value without making x as protected!

Comment: No, private means private, and nobody outside of the defining class can see it.   Again, the entire *point* of protected is so derived classes can see parent's members, while nobody else can.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the private / protected issue, your `B::x` member *over-shades* the `x` of `A`. So even if both were public, you'd have to write `b.A::x`. Looks weird, but works (see code below) ....

This is syntax-wise. You should tot do this, of course, as everybody here say. use protected members with meaningful names, and accessor functions

```
class A {
public:
  int x;
};

class B: public A {
public:
  int x;
  void f() { std::cout << "B::x=" << x << ", A::x=" << A::x << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  b.A::x = 10;
  b.x = 20;
  b.f();
}
```

output:

```
B::x=20, A::x=10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not examine the value of private members of base class.  So: add an accessor in A or make A::x protected.

Answer (score 0):

Make x in A protected and write a method in B that looks something like this:

```
int getAX(){
  return A::x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't.

Since your `A` class tells the member is private, nobody but `A` can access it.

If `B` is-an-`A`, the same rule is valid: `A::x` is still inaccessible.

Your wanting to access it means you either need a different kind of `A` (i.e. make `A::x` public), or you want the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to know if it's possible: it is. `public`, `protected` and `private` are only compile time checks. One possible option to circumvent them during runtime is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
    int x;
    A() : x(10){}
};
struct pubA{
    int x;
};

int main(){
    A a;
    // evil casting
    pubA* pa = reinterpret_cast<A*>(&a);
    std::cout << pa->x << std::endl; // should print 10
}
```

That said, **don't do it**. There is a reason for these keywords. (The above code is untested, 'caus I'm writing from my iPod. If `reinterpret_cast` doesn't work, use old C-style cast: `pa = (pubA*)&a`.)